# What does datatype.text validate against?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a production application that is being hit on our security scans for [CWE-100](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/100.html). I know that this is a deprecated item, however it is still showing on my report.

At the moment I only see two actions to take,

1. Handle each item and clear the flaw on the report
2. Mark the flaw and comment that it is deprecated and go talk to my security team.

With regards to fixing it I found that adding a datatype attribute to the variable removed the warning. Here is a snippet of the ones I have fixed

```
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
public string Name { get; set; }
...
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter documentation.")]
public string Documentation{ get; set; }
```

I could not find any documentation from Microsoft on what this datatype attribute validates against. If it even does, as from some minor testing I can still enter any character I copy into the text box I display for this.

Is there a reason to add this attribute, or would I be wasting my time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: This is just my understanding from reading the [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations) (feel free to correct me)

([DataTypeAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/DataTypeAttribute.cs)) is a `ValidationAttribute` (derived from `ValidationAttribute`) and you need to pass it an [Enum](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/src/System/ComponentModel/DataAnnotations/DataType.cs) (which is also called `DataType`).

Validation Attributes need to override `IsValid` method, which is executed on model binding, and need to determine if the value is valid or not. This is how a custom validator would look like:

```
public class CustomValidator : ValidationAttribute  
{  
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)  
    {  
        // do some validation

        if (/* validation passes */)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;  
        }
        else 
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Validation message..."); 
        }
    }  
}
```

Now, getting back to `DataTypeAttribue` (which is a validation attribute), you need to pass it `DataType` enum:

```
public enum DataType
{
    Custom = 0,
    DateTime = 1,
    Date = 2,
    Time = 3,
    Duration = 4,
    PhoneNumber = 5,
    Currency = 6,
    Text = 7,
    Html = 8,
    MultilineText = 9,
    EmailAddress = 10,
    Password = 11,
    Url = 12,
    ImageUrl = 13,
    CreditCard = 14,
    PostalCode = 15,
    Upload = 16
}
```

From what I can see, all that `DataTypeAttribtue` does, is to add some formatting for `DataType.Date`, `DataType.Time` and `DataType.Currency`... (also set the `_dataTypeStrings`)

Further more, you have validation attributes like [EmailAddressAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/EmailAddressAttribute.cs), [PhoneAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/PhoneAttribute.cs), [UrlAttribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs), etc which are derived from `DataTypeAttribute` and do extra validation for these specific types:

Now this is how you can use these validation attributes:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Phone] // <- executes the IsValid method of PhoneAttribute
    public String Home { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)] // <- does NOT execute IsValid method of PhoneAttribute
    public String Mobile { get; set; }

    [EmailAddress] // <- executes the IsValid method of EmailAddressAttribute
    public String Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)] // <- does the Currency formatting
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]  // <- does the Date formatting
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)] // <- does NOT add any validation/formatting
    public string Name { get; set;}

    /*
     * this is the only scenario that I can think of, for using: [DataType(DataType.Text)]
     */
    [DataType(DataType.Text)] 
    public object someKey { get; set;}

}
```

Again, from what I can understand, adding `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` to `string`, 
does not add any value, and is better not to use it to keep the code smaller, cleaner and easier to understand...

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I will go through and make sure all the cases are same as I have stated here, and will just talk to my security team.

Do you know what the text validates against?
I have used others like in your answer, date, email, password etc. But I have no idea what the text one does.

Comment: @JRHigdon: I have updated the answer... as far as I understand `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` does not do anything, if you use it on a `string` type.