# Does this annotation make any difference [DataType(DataType.Text)]

Tags: c#, .net, validation

There is any difference between these two classes User & User1?

I know this annotation allows validation with different type
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype?view=net-5.0

But I can't figure out what can be validated as text?

```
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Security;
     
    namespace AspNetMvc.Models
    {
        public class User
        {
            [DataType(DataType.Text)]
            public string UserName { get; set; } 
        }

        public class User1
        {           
            public string UserName { get; set; }     
        }
    }
```

Comment: The description of that annotation is `Represents text that is displayed`. That to me is not very useful for validation indeed. Almost any other type except Custom could pass the `DataType.Text` validation.

Comment: @Cleptus
You're right, it doesn't validate 

I found some explanation here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53876806/7883971

This make sense

 /*
     * this is the only scenario that I can think of, for using: [DataType(DataType.Text)]
     */
    [DataType(DataType.Text)] 
    public object someKey { get; set;}